# autoenv printing "will run" /path/to/.env everytime I cd

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenv

My specific problem is not the fact that `source /venv/bin/activate` is being executed everytime I change to a sub folder. The problem is everytime I do it prints "will run" /path/to/.env

I installed autoenv through homebrew in version 0.2.0. This is my `.env` file:

```
if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
    CUR_DIR=$(pwd)
    # search for the next .env
    while [[ "$PWD" != "/" && "$PWD" != "$home" ]]; do
        env_file="$PWD/.env"
        if [[ -f "$env_file" ]]; then
            BASE_DIR=$(dirname $env_file)
            break
        fi
        builtin cd ..
    done

    if [ ! -z "$BASE_DIR" ]; then
        echo "Activating that virtualenv"
        source ${BASE_DIR}/venv/bin/activate
    fi

    cd $CUR_DIR
fi
```

The output in the terminal is something like:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ llamasramirez$ cd Desktop/oficios/
Will run /Users/llamas/Desktop/oficios/.env
Activating that virtualenv
Will run /Users/llamas/Desktop/oficios/.env
(venv) MacBook-Pro:oficios llamasramirez$ cd django_sites/polls/
Will run /Users/llamas/Desktop/oficios/.env
(venv) MacBook-Pro:polls llamasramirez$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't in the `.env` file. The problem was at the `activate.sh` file.

Opening the `autoenv_init` function there's a for loop that makes the annoying echo instruction:

```
for _file in ${_orderedfiles}; do
    echo "Will run ${_file}"
    autoenv_check_authz_and_run "${_file}"
done
```

When I comment this the echo doesn't pops up again.